# How can I implement Paypal client side payment on Android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, paypal

I am trying to add Paypal inside my application. However, it throws me the following error:

```
    org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myFirstApp'.
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'mavenUsername' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.
```

Here is my gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
mavenUsername=paypal_sgerritz
mavenPassword=AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ
```

And build.gradle here:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url  "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                username mavenUsername
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is wrong with this library?? Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: it's probably a bad idea to post your username and password here..

Comment: @IvoBeckers It's not my Username and Password. It's the default Username and Password that Paypal give as an example. Check out this: [link](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/in-app/android/)

Comment: Are your gradle.properties located in the correct place (root project folder)?

Comment: @romtsn Yeah, I think so.

Comment: @Rider25 you think so, or they are? :)

Comment: @romtsn Well, I searched again and indeed `gradle.properties` weren't located in the correct place. You were right. Thank you

Comment: So I guess that solves the problem? I will just post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `gradle.properties` is located in the root project (or rather, that your `mavenUsername` and `mavenPassword` are in the root project's `gradle.properties`)